# How do I upgrade PHP version in macOS Server?

Tags: php, macos, server

Good day,

Just to clarify, I'm asking about macOS Server, the application published by Apple. I'm not referring to the system's PHP version.

I've looked everywhere, Google, SO, forums, for quite some time and haven't found a solution.

I'm unable to upgrade my PHP version for macOS Server no matter what I try. There's just simply no documentation.

I've updated the app from the App Store, I've upgraded my PHP version on my Mac, and I've changed the `PATH` to reflect the new PHP install, and when I do `php -v` in Terminal, it shows the correct version I want.

However, macOS Server seems complete unaffected by it. I tried looking around everywhere possible, but I don't see a separate install of PHP for Server, and I looked in the config files, everywhere, but can't see where and which PHP it's using.

Any help?

EDIT: I just realised that it's a whole application which many parts actively use PHP, and upgrading it on my own may break those things, but I'm willing to give it a shot, if it's at all possible. I mean, the worst that can happen is for me to delete and re-install Server, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Installing php on macOS

> *Honestly, you sound like you know more about this than is evident in the question. So you probably know a lot of this, but I wanted to be as complete as I can, from my experience, since these responses remain for others who may locate them in the future and find the information useful. If I have left anything out, I hope someone will point it out for me so I can learn a bit more along the way.*

#### Back in the day, then thunder gods ruled the world:

`php` has come bundled standard on Macs since Mac OS X version 10.0.0, as you can read about [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php). The first version of Mac OS X Server (1.0) was a hybrid of OPENSTEP from Steve Jobs' NeXT Computer and Mac OS 8.5.1 released in 1999.

[Starting with Mac OS X 10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Server) (Lion) Mac OS X and Mac OS X Server have been combined into one operating system package and the macOS Server is an add-on package available through the App Store. This means that you can't really worry very much about ruining anything too important.

#### You can't always get what you want ...

A lot of the value in this response will depend on what you use the Server package for. If you only use the web server for a development environment, it can easily be replaced with any version of the typical LAMP (linux-apache-mysql-php) style environment.

For macOS, this means upgrade apache, install [php](https://www.php.net/downloads.php), and install [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) if you cannot use [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) that comes bundled with macOS. [Here is one of the many](https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/update-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-sierra//) great tutorials available online. (no affiliation) It can get complicated ...

Another option that is popular, but that I haven't used myself, is the non-profit [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). They are focused on making it simpler to setup php development, Wordpress, Drupal, e-commerce, and popular open source apps.

#### When you're a stranger ...

If you are using some of the more esoteric apps that came with the server package, you will have to upgrade them separately. But since you are asking about php and the server recognizing it, I'm assuming you are talking about the web server and that you are using something like this to see what php version apache is finding:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Most likely, what you are saying is that the command line php version shows correct versions and settings, but the web page version served by apache shows the old version. Is that right?

#### Version and File Locations:

I'm not sure if you have checked for this, but the first thing I would do is find out for sure what the path is and what version I am using. This also gives me a quick direct link to the ini file so I can go break stuff faster. Here are my results (screenshot at the end) using `php --version` and `php --ini`:

```
$ which php

/usr/local/bin/php

$ php --version

PHP 7.3.6 (cli) (built: May 31 2019 23:38:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.6, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

$ php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

#### A touch too much:

Using `php -i` will output an enormous amount of information. It is many pages ... more than you would ever want. If you are looking for specifics, you can grep it for whatever you like: `php -i | grep ini` or `php -i | grep -- '--with'` to look for options.

#### Hiding in plain sight:

Most likely you are checking, testing, and upgrading the wrong installation of `php` or `apache`. macOS is infamous for having standard versions of many programs and it will likely break something if you upgrade the 'system' version of any of them.

`Ruby` and `Python` are the most common ones to cause problems for me. I have never had any issue with php, but there and many workarounds available for many programs (e.g. [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) for gnu).

#### Homebrew!

The easiest way I have found is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install a separate version that you can manage and upgrade as you like and link it somewhere early in your path so it is always the first version found.

```
$ brew install php
```

It does everything for you and keeps it updated. It also allows php to always be running as a service using `brew services start php`. This reduces startup time and prevents some multiple version issues. A list of all brew services and status info is, as you might expect, found with `brew services list`. If you update any config or ini files, you should restart php (and apache) with `brew services restart php`. You can also still use `launchctl` and `apachectl` if you choose.

#### Apache!

The other handy thing about homebrew is that you can use it to install and manage `apache2`, also. Try this:

```
$ brew install httpd
$ brew services start httpd
$ httpd
```

#### Non-alcoholic recipe:

If you prefer to abstain and not use homebrew, you can install any version you wish from [php.net](https://www.php.net/downloads.php) and make a link in a directory early in your `PATH`. Patches and upgrades are regular and everything is extremely professional and well (over?) documented.

[image]

Download a php binary, check it with the provided signatures, and link it somewhere on your path: `ln -s /path/to/new/php ~/bin/php` or somewhere else if you don't use your /home/bin. Homebrew puts the link in `/usr/local/bin` by default.

No matter which method you choose, after you install the programs you will definitely have to adjust a few settings. There are several great posts online about this. [This one](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-multiple-php-versions) is a multi-part series and is updated for Mojave. The main information to get you started should be available as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]